# Safari can't access to ipv6 address whereas Chrome can do

Tags: safari, vpn, ipv6

When using Cisco OpenConnect client there are no problems resolving IPv6 only sites. However while using open source openconnect command line client from brew Safari can't resolve IPv6 only sites. Open source openconnect uses vpnc script to configure network interfaces. IPv6 address is assigned and connectivity is working just fine.

Same problem with OpenVPN, both open source and proprietary OpenVPN.net client.

While searching for an answer I came across a question first posted on apple communities exactly three years ago:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/24511921
but it does not provide any command line solutions suitable for adding to vpnc script.

Are here any scutil experts? I suppose there should be away to mark a VPN interface utun0 as IPv6 enabled. At least official Cisco OpenConnect client somehow does it just fine.

Comment: While connected to the VPN which is not working properly, open a Terminal and collect the output of the `ifconfig` command and the `netstat -nr` command, and edit your question to include them. Please avoid obfuscating anything if possible, as you may inadvertently destroy information that is important to diagnosing the problem.

Comment: VPN is working properly. It is expected that "scutil --dns" returns "Request AAAA records" among other things when ipv6 device is created.